# Random comma in Table

Tags: tables, rotating, compilation-error

I have a made a table with the sidewaytable package and got a weird comma in the center of the table and don't know where its coming from. Any ideas?

```
%... 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\sffamily,\footnotesize}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\sffamily}
\usepackage[footnotesize,font=sf]{caption}

%...

    \begin{sidewaystable}[h!]   
        \begin{center}
            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
            \caption{Adapted from \textcite{Kounadi2020}: Overview of related spatial crime forecasting studies} 
            \label{tabRelWork}
                \begin{tabular} {>{\raggedright}p{2.4cm}>{\raggedright}p{2cm}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.8cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.6cm}>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm}p{1.2cm}}
        
                \toprule
                    \textbf{Source}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Space}}&  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Time}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Crime data}}&\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Forecasting}}\\
                \cmidrule(l{.5em}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{.5em}){4-5} \cmidrule(l{.5em}){6-7} \cmidrule(l{.5em}){8-11}
                    & \textbf{Study Area} & \textbf{Scale} & \textbf{Sampling period} & \textbf{Months} & \textbf{Type} &  \textbf{Samples} & \textbf{Inference} & \textbf{Task} & \textbf{Spatial Unit} & \textbf{Temporal unit}\\
                \midrule
                    \textcite{Brown2001}&Richmond, VA, USA&City&1994–1999&72&Breaking and entering&$ \lessapprox $24.000&Number of crimes&Regression&$\approx0.64mi^{2}$ $(\approx1,65km^{2})$ grid cells&Week, Month\\
                    \textcite{Cohen2007}&Pittsburgh, PA, USA&City&1991-1998&96&Violent and property&1,3 million&Number of crimes&Regression&$4.000ft$ $(\approx1.220m)$ \newline sq. grid cells&Month\\
                    \textcite{Dash2018}&Chicago, IL, USA&City&2011–2015&60&34 crime types&6,6 million&Number of crimes&Regression&Communities&Month, Year\\
                    \textcite{Gorr2003b}&Pittsburgh, PA, USA&City&1991-1998&96&5 crime types&$ \approx $1 million&Number of crimes&Regression&Police precincts&Month\\
                    \textcite{Ivaha2007}&Cardiff, UK&City&2001-2003&26&Criminal damage&N.A.&\% of crime in clusters&Regression&Clusters of varying size&Month\\
                    \textcite{Kadar2018}&New York, NY, USA&City&2014–2015&24&All and 5 crime types&174.682&Number of crimes&Regression&Census tract&Year\\
                    \textcite{Liesenfeld2017}&Pittsburgh, PA, USA&City&2008–2013&72&All crimes&9.936&Number of crimes&Regression&Census tract&Month, Year\\
                    \textcite{Rentzelos2020}&New York, NY, USA&City&2016&12&All, violent and property&312.403&Hot spots&Regression&Zip codes&Week\\
                    \textcite{Rodriguez2017}&San Francisco, CA, USA&City&2003–2013&120&Burglary&N.A.&Properties of clusters&Regression&Clusters&Day\\
                    \textcite{Shoesmith2013}&USA&Country&1960-2009&600&Violent and property&N.A.&Crime rate&Regression&Regions of USA&Year\\
                    \textcite{Zhao2017}&New York, NY, USA&City&2012-2013&12&N.A.&N.A.&Number of crimes&Regression&$ 2km $ sq. grid cell&Day, Week\\
                    \textcite{Zhuang2017}&Portland, OR, USA&City&2012-2016&58&All crime&N.A.&Hot spots&Binary classification&$ 600ft $ $(\approx180m)$ \newline sq. grid cells&2 Weeks\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{sidewaystable}
```

[image: A image of the comma in the table]

cheers

Comment: I guess it's this comma: `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\sffamily,\footnotesize}`

Comment: The argument to `\AtBeginEnvironment` is not a “list of options”, but simply code to be executed at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `\AtBeginEnvironment` is not a “list of options”, but simply code to be executed at the appropriate time.

So, instead of

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\sffamily,\footnotesize}
```

remove the comma and use

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
```

(answer extracted from comments)